Logic Apps Post Request to run Databricks notebook
I've created a http action within my logic apps that processes a post request to execute a Databricks notebook.
This is the error im getting:
{
    "statusCode": 401,
    "headers": {
        "WWW-Authenticate": "basic realm=\"DatabricksRealm\"",
        "x-databricks-reason-phrase": "Unauthorized",
        "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
        "Date": "Tue, 06 Aug 2024 00:08:59 GMT",
        "Server": "databricks",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Content-Length": "45"
    },
    "body": {
        "error_code": "401",
        "message": "Unauthorized"
    }
}



I've specified the job id within the body and the url to my notebook. I'm using the API Key from databricks as authorization for my custom connector. Am i missing permissions to my logic app since I'm accessing databricks within my logic app?

You do not need to use custom connector here, directly you can give in Headers as Authorization is Bearer TokenValue. Below design worked for me:

Output:
The Job is executed as below:


If you do not give Authorization in Http connector it wont work.

this works! Thank you :)
